# FPDF: When using MultiCell, inserting a Row does not work correctly when there's a page break

Tags: php, fpdf

I have a PHP code that uses **FPDF** to generate an invoice as PDF. I am trying to  insert 100 rows on the detail using a `FOR` loop. Since I am using `MultiCell` I need to know whether there is a page break before inserting the row.

this is my code:

```
    //Detalle de Factura

$pdf->Cell(20,5,utf8_decode('Código'),0,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(60,5,utf8_decode('Descripción'),0,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(20,5,utf8_decode('Cantidad'),0,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(30,5,utf8_decode('Precio Unidad'),0,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(20,5,utf8_decode('Porc. IV'),0,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(30,5,utf8_decode('Impuesto'),0,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(30,5,utf8_decode('Total'),0,0,'L',0);

$pdf->Ln();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);

for($i=0; $i<=100; $i++)
{
    $x = $pdf->GetX();
    $y = $pdf->GetY();

    $pdf->MultiCell(20,5,utf8_decode('Codigo 123467890'),0);//Celda con varias lineas

    $pdf->SetXY($x + 20, $y);

    $x = $pdf->GetX();
    $y = $pdf->GetY();

    $pdf->MultiCell(60,5,utf8_decode('ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd'),0);//Celda con varias lineas

    $pdf->SetXY($x + 60, $y);

    $x = $pdf->GetX();
    $y = $pdf->GetY();

    $pdf->MultiCell(20,5,utf8_decode('5000000000'),0);//Celda con varias lineas

    $pdf->SetXY($x + 20, $y);

    $x = $pdf->GetX();
    $y = $pdf->GetY();

    $pdf->MultiCell(30,5,utf8_decode('5000000000'),0);//Celda con varias lineas

    $pdf->SetXY($x + 30, $y);

    $x = $pdf->GetX();
    $y = $pdf->GetY();

    $pdf->MultiCell(20,5,utf8_decode('5000000000'),0);//Celda con varias lineas

    $pdf->SetXY($x + 20, $y);

    $x = $pdf->GetX();
    $y = $pdf->GetY();

    $pdf->MultiCell(30,5,utf8_decode('5000000000'),0);//Celda con varias lineas

    $pdf->SetXY($x + 30, $y);

    $x = $pdf->GetX();
    $y = $pdf->GetY();

    $pdf->MultiCell(30,5,utf8_decode('5000000000'),0);//Celda con varias lineas 

    $pdf->Ln();
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "the cursor position does not work any more". Is that all of your code or do you have a header function defined for your document? There is nothing in your code that should cause determining where the cursor is to stop working.

Comment: I needed to check if there was a page break before inserting a new row. But I found the solution already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was using `MultiCell` I needed to check if there was going to be a page break before inserting a new row, and if there was, then insert the row in the next page. I found the solution searching the internet. this is the link that help me out:

[Table with MultiCells](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php)

**Source**

```
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF_MC_Table extends FPDF
{
var $widths;
var $aligns;

function SetWidths($w)
{
    //Set the array of column widths
    $this->widths=$w;
}

function SetAligns($a)
{
    //Set the array of column alignments
    $this->aligns=$a;
}

function Row($data)
{
    //Calculate the height of the row
    $nb=0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
        $nb=max($nb,$this->NbLines($this->widths[$i],$data[$i]));
    $h=5*$nb;
    //Issue a page break first if needed
    $this->CheckPageBreak($h);
    //Draw the cells of the row
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
    {
        $w=$this->widths[$i];
        $a=isset($this->aligns[$i]) ? $this->aligns[$i] : 'L';
        //Save the current position
        $x=$this->GetX();
        $y=$this->GetY();
        //Draw the border
        $this->Rect($x,$y,$w,$h);
        //Print the text
        $this->MultiCell($w,5,$data[$i],0,$a);
        //Put the position to the right of the cell
        $this->SetXY($x+$w,$y);
    }
    //Go to the next line
    $this->Ln($h);
}

function CheckPageBreak($h)
{
    //If the height h would cause an overflow, add a new page immediately
    if($this->GetY()+$h>$this->PageBreakTrigger)
        $this->AddPage($this->CurOrientation);
}

function NbLines($w,$txt)
{
    //Computes the number of lines a MultiCell of width w will take
    $cw=&$this->CurrentFont['cw'];
    if($w==0)
        $w=$this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;
    $wmax=($w-2*$this->cMargin)*1000/$this->FontSize;
    $s=str_replace("\r",'',$txt);
    $nb=strlen($s);
    if($nb>0 and $s[$nb-1]=="\n")
        $nb--;
    $sep=-1;
    $i=0;
    $j=0;
    $l=0;
    $nl=1;
    while($i<$nb)
    {
        $c=$s[$i];
        if($c=="\n")
        {
            $i++;
            $sep=-1;
            $j=$i;
            $l=0;
            $nl++;
            continue;
        }
        if($c==' ')
            $sep=$i;
        $l+=$cw[$c];
        if($l>$wmax)
        {
            if($sep==-1)
            {
                if($i==$j)
                    $i++;
            }
            else
                $i=$sep+1;
            $sep=-1;
            $j=$i;
            $l=0;
            $nl++;
        }
        else
            $i++;
    }
    return $nl;
}
}
```

**Example**

```
require('mc_table.php');

function GenerateWord()
{
    //Get a random word
    $nb=rand(3,10);
    $w='';
    for($i=1;$i<=$nb;$i++)
        $w.=chr(rand(ord('a'),ord('z')));
    return $w;
}

function GenerateSentence()
{
    //Get a random sentence
    $nb=rand(1,10);
    $s='';
    for($i=1;$i<=$nb;$i++)
        $s.=GenerateWord().' ';
    return substr($s,0,-1);
}

$pdf=new PDF_MC_Table();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);
//Table with 20 rows and 4 columns
$pdf->SetWidths(array(30,50,30,40));

for($i=0;$i<20;$i++)
    $pdf->Row(array(GenerateSentence(),GenerateSentence(),GenerateSentence(),GenerateSentence()));
$pdf->Output();
```